# Browser : Tool allowing to do Logins with different account into same Website

Tags: browser, load-testing

I have written some code related to User Login .

I need to test my WebSite how it behaves when logged in with Multiple Accounts simultanesly at the same time .

Till now i have been testing this manually , by opening multiple Tabs and logging into it using different accounts .

For example

```
http:localhost:8080/logon   USERNAME  PWD
http:localhost:8080/logon  USERNAME  PWD
http:localhost:8080/logon  USERNAME  PWD
http:localhost:8080/logon  USERNAME  PWD
```

Is there any way i can automate this , i mean any such  browser plug which allows to Login with different accounts ??

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you're looking for "[web load testing software](https://www.google.com/#hl=en&tbo=d&output=search&sclient=psy-ab&q=web+load+testing+software&oq=web+load+testing+software&gs_l=hp.3..0j0i5j0i5i30j0i8i30.997.997.0.2108.1.1.0.0.0.0.132.132.0j1.1.0.les;..0.0...1c.1.0YhCGkmNdtY&pbx=1&bav=on.2,or.r_gc.r_pw.r_cp.r_qf.&fp=c2a7c58b272ed651&bpcl=37189454&biw=1414&bih=1162)". Google will give you lots of options.

I'll recommend that you start with something easy to use, such as Web Performance Load Tester. The [LITE version](https://www.webperformance.com/load-testing/free-load-tester-lite.html) is free and can probably do much of what you need. Disclaimer: I'm the lead engineer for the product.